# counting overall results with groups in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

I see some questions that get at issues similar to this one, but I can't find any that quite catch it.

I'm working with this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.word) FROM concordance a, bigdic b 
                    WHERE a.word = b.word
                    and a.word LIKE '%" . $name .  "%'"
```

It works fine as it is, but I want to eliminate cases where `word` is duplicated in table `b`. If I add `GROUP BY b.word`, the query returns the count of the first group instead of the overall count minus the duplicates, whereas the right total would be the count of the groups. How do I get that total instead?

Comment: You might want `count(distinct a.word)`, but the question can be interpreted in multiple ways. Adding some sample data and required result would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select distinct words from `b` in a subquery and then join the result back to `a`, in this way only the unique words from `b` will be joined to `a`.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(a.word) 
FROM concordance a
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT b.word
      FROM bigdic b) temp
ON temp.word = a.word
WHERE a.word LIKE '%" . $name .  "%'"
```

Comment: You could also follow @Lawrence suggestion, it's not very clear from your question but using `DISTINCT a.word` could work too, it all comes down on your data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It can be more efficient to phrase this as an `exists` query:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.word)
FROM concordance a
WHERE a.word LIKE '%" . $name .  "%'"
WHERE exists (select 1 from bigdic b.word = b.word);
```

Particularly if you have an index on `bigdic(word)`.